# Google app script: Compare values from two spreadsheets and set a marker

Tags: google-apps-script

I just cant find my error on this simple code. Can someone enlighten me?

I want to compare two columns of to spreadsheets within one google sheet.

- Sheet one is "Mahnwesen aus Datev"
- Sheet two is "Dazev OP Liste _NEU"

Both sheets have a column with invoice numbers that I need to compare.

- Sheet one has the numbers in column "W"
- Sheet two in column "C"

I basically want to compare these and if the number of Sheet one, column "W" is the same as in sheet two in column "C" and then write me *"Yes in the List"* to the sheet one in column "C".

Running my script is returning only one result ins sheet one "C4" which leads to a wrong range statement or something? Sorry I am only a starter in google script...

This is what I tried:

```
function wertVergleich() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mahnwesen aus DATEV");
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Datev OP Liste_NEU");

    var startzeile = 3; // Zeile ab der die Suche beginnen soll
    var markierungsSpaltenIndex = 3; // Spalte in der die Markierung gesetzt werden soll
    var markierung = "JA in Datev OP Liste"; // Markierung die gesetzt werden soll
    var daten = sheet2.getRange("C3:C" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Daten holen
    
    var aktuelleZeilennummer = startzeile; // Variable die anzeigt in welcher Zeile wir uns befinden
  
    for (x in daten) {
        var zellInhalt = daten[x];
 
        if (zellInhalt == sheet1.getRange("W3:W").getValue()) {
            sheet1.setActiveRange(sheet1.getRange(aktuelleZeilennummer, markierungsSpaltenIndex)).setValue(markierung);
        }
        
        aktuelleZeilennummer++;
    }
    debugger;
}
```

I also found this in another article on this forum, but got the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> (Anonym)  @ Makros.gs:248
> findDuplicate @ Makros.gs:247":

```
function findDuplicate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Mahnwesen aus DATEV'); 
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange('W3:W' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Datev OP Liste_NEU'); 
  const vs2 = sh1.getRange('C3:C' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  let o = [];
  vs1.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == vs2[i][0]) {
      o.push(vs2[i][1]);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  return o;
}
```

Sources:
where https://toptorials.com/werte-aus-zellen-ueber-ein-script-vergleichen-mit-google-tabellen/
https://toptorials.com/zellen-vergleichen-markieren-array-google-tabellen-script/

Comment: Try using indexOf() on one of the columns

Comment: If sheet 2 column C contains the invoice number, you want to overwrite it with "Yes in the List"? Won't you lose the ability to compare with sheet 1 column W in the future?  Why not put the text in another column of sheet 2, or a lot of people add a datestamp to the end of the row.?

Comment: hey @TheWizEd - Yes this is what i wanted. Maybe I wrote it wrong. I compare sheet 1 with the numbers in "W" with sheet 2 ind "C" if there are equal write th sheet 1 in C "yes equal"

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

*Issues found in your script:*

- On the line `if (zellInhalt == sheet1.getRange("W3:W").getValue()) {`, only the first value (`10089`) is being used in your loop
  ***repeatedly*** because you're using the `getValue()` method on `sheet1.getRange("W3:W").getValue()`. It's the reason why there's
  only one result in **sheet 1** as it will just match one piece of
  data.

### [UPDATED]

- Based on your comment, you want to get the behaviour similar to `VLOOKUP` using the script.
- Check every values in the `Sheet 1` column **W** (*as a **search key***) if it exists in `Sheet 2` column **C** (*as the **range***)
- Mark any values that exist in the `Sheet 1` column **C** adjacent to the matched value from Column **W**.

***Perhaps you could try this tweaked script:***

```
function wertVergleich() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mahnwesen aus Datev");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Datev OP Liste_NEU");

  var startzeile = 3; // Zeile ab der die Suche beginnen soll
  var markierungsSpaltenIndex = 3; // Spalte in der die Markierung gesetzt werden soll
  var markierung = "JA in Datev OP Liste"; // Zu setzende Markierung
  var range = sheet2.getRange("C3:C" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues(); // Daten von Blatt 1 abrufen
  var searchKey = sheet1.getRange("W3:W" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues(); // Daten von Blatt 2 abrufen
  var ergebnis = searchKey.map(x => range.join(' , ').match(x[0]) ? [markierung] : [''])

  sheet1.getRange(startzeile, markierungsSpaltenIndex, ergebnis.length).setValues(ergebnis);
}
```

### Demo

> *NOTE: Numbers in **bold text** are the ones with a match on the other sheet.*

- ***Test Sheet 1***

> [image]

- ***Test Sheet 2***

> [image]

- ***After running the script***

> [image]

### References

- [JavaScript Array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [JavaScript String match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Comment: @Sarah I hope this one helps. If there's anything else that's missing or misunderstood, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! So I tried your script on my sheet, and still have the same result - only the first row will be checked. i have also tested my version, taking your correction into account, but without success. I even rebuild your testsheet and tested it there...

Could it be the formatting of the numbers? I know I can also do this with a formula, but this should run in the background and I would otherwise have to create it with Arrayformula() and that leads to problems with other scripts.

Comment: I see, when I put the same row of data to both sheet, it is comparing and finding the data. I missed to point out, that the data order is different on each columns. So the script is not working. I basically need an VLOOKUP as script.

Comment: @Sarah I have updated my answer. If there's anything still missing, if you could share a sample sheet with data similar to your actual sheet for replication, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are my hero! It worked perfectly, smooth and fast. Thank so much! Shall I still add a sample sheet?

Comment: @Sarah I'm glad that the tweaked script worked. You are very welcome. The sample sheet is no longer needed in this case. Lastly, you may want to click the ***accept/upvote*** button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same question as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.